I create a VSIX Project with usage of an external compiler and want to add F1
I create a VSIX Project with usage of an external compiler and want to add F1. I'm able to get the F2 key and so on, but the F1 key doesn't work.
    public partial class OutputWindowControl : UserControl
    {

        // Rest of code...

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            // Loggen Sie den Wert von e.Key
            Logging.WriteLine("3 Key pressed: " + e.Key);

            if (e.Key == Key.F1)
            {
                Logging.WriteLine("F1 pressed");
            }
        }

}

Please gib´ve me an idea, what I've to do.
Greeting
Kai
Same with:
private void OutputWindowControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        


What is OutputWindowControl? Do you want F1 to be registered as hotkey?

It seems that the logic is correct and consistent with the general usage. How is your xaml part written?

@Sinatr
OutputWindowControl is a XAML Control with a TextBox. I want to open my own Help from this window / control. F2 works. F1 not.

@Bowman Zhu-MSFT
The XAML is
<UserControl x:Class="FourDGAssist.OutputWindowControl"

         Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}"
         Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"


<Grid x:Name="GridTool">
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="outputTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</Grid>

